# Можно ли управлять тем, какой поток будет пробужден при вызове notify_all / notify_one? C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Проблема: Есть N потоков, которые управляются одной std::condition_variable. Этой же переключалкой управляется и основной поток, который ждет завершения всех N потоков (про join забудем в рамках вопроса). Каждый поток после завершения зовет notify_all, что может привести к тому, что пробудится основной поток и продолжит своё выполнение.

Вопрос в шапке.